# Joomla based website displaying modules despite being deselected on that page

Tags: joomla3.0

I have a Joomla website [here](http://dmvspotlight.com/j3x/) and when you click on an article from the homepage it stills displays all of the home page modules. I went thru the settings for each module, and it is set to display only on the home menu page. I go to the menu setting that the articles are under and the settings stated the modules are published but not displayed. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I checked Your site and don't see any homepage modules when I go to article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue was due to a category error. The category is supposed to auto create a page for itself, however, it did not happen for whatever reason. So I had to delete the category and then make the category again and everything was fine. The reason the home page modules were appearing on articles is because that's the default behavior of Joomla when it can not find a specific page.